# Error: deferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c

I have seen this question/error a lot but I just can't figure out what is wrong. I created a structure that contains some information about a thread and just basically I want to assign some values (thread number, current thread... etc) everytime I create a thread. The threads are not relevant for this error. So far, I am just trying to make my struct work but I keep getting an error for deferencing pointer to incomplete type for the part of

`thread->num=num;`

Is it a memory allocation error? Or any clue?
Here is my code:

main.c // does not give me any error

```
struct sPRIME_THREAD *new_thread = create_thread(1,0,0,20);
printf("Thread Info:\n");
print_info(new_thread);
```

header.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Macro definitions */
#define MAX_THREADS     5   // Maximum number of prime search threads

/* Data types */
typedef struct              // Prime search thread data
{
    unsigned int num;       // Prime search thread number
    unsigned int current;   // Number currently evaluating for primality
    unsigned int low;       // Low end of range to test for primality
    unsigned int high;      // High end of range to test for primality
} sPRIME_THREAD;

/* Shared global variables */
extern sPRIME_THREAD primeThreadData[MAX_THREADS];  // Prime search thread data
int numThreads;                                     // Number of prime search threads

struct sPRIME_THREAD *create_thread(unsigned int num, unsigned int current,
                                    unsigned int low, unsigned int high) 
    {
        struct sPRIME_THREAD *thread = (sPRIME_THREAD *)malloc(sizeof(sPRIME_THREAD));

        thread->num = num;
        thread->current = current;
        thread->low = low;
        thread->high = high;

        return thread;
    }

void destroy_thread(struct sPRIME_THREAD *thread) 
{
    free(thread);
}

void print_info(struct sPRIME_THREAD *thread) 
{
    printf("Num: %d\n", thread->num);
    printf("Current: %d\n", thread->current);
    printf("Low: %d\n", thread->low);
    printf("High: %d\n", thread->high); 
}
```

Comment: `struct sPRIME_THREAD` is undefined. By doing `typedef struct {...}  sPRIME_THREAD;` you just define the type `sPRIME_THREA`.

Comment: I tried doing   
    typedef struct sPRIME_THREAD { ... } sPRIME_THREAD;
and I get a lot of multiple definition errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`struct sPRIME_THREAD` is undefined. By doing `typedef struct {...}  sPRIME_THREAD;` you just define an anonymous `struct` to be the type `sPRIME_THREAD`.

To fix this drop the typedef

```
typedef struct              
{
  unsigned int num;       
  unsigned int current;  
  unsigned int low;       
  unsigned int high;     
} sPRIME_THREAD;
```

and define a `struct` type by

```
struct sPRIME_THREAD             
{
  unsigned int num;      
  unsigned int current;  
  unsigned int low;       
  unsigned int high;     
};
```

and always use `struct sPRIME_THREAD` when refering to the type.

Comment: I tried doing that before and got even more errors, example of these are:
`ilopez_prime.h:24:8: error: name of type ‘sPRIME_THREAD’ is unknown
 extern sPRIME_THREAD primeThreadData[MAX_THREADS]; 
ilopez_prime.h: In function ‘create_thread’:
ilopez_prime.h:30:35: error: ‘sPRIME_THREAD’ was not declared here    struct sPRIME_THREAD *thread = (sPRIME_THREAD *)malloc(sizeof(sPRIME_THREAD));
`

Comment: The `struct`-type is `struct sPRIME_THREAD` not just `sPRIME_THREAD`.

Comment: Oh yes, I see now your comment. My apologies, that actually fixed it. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

No need of using `struct` keyword, if you are using `typedef` . Refer [typedef](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/typedef)

check this

```
/* Data types */
typedef struct              // Prime search thread data
{
unsigned int num;       // Prime search thread number
unsigned int current;   // Number currently evaluating for primality
unsigned int low;       // Low end of range to test for primality
unsigned int high;      // High end of range to test for primality
} sPRIME_THREAD;

/* Shared global variables */
extern sPRIME_THREAD primeThreadData[MAX_THREADS];  // Prime search    thread data
int numThreads;                                     // Number of prime    search threads

sPRIME_THREAD *create_thread(unsigned int num, unsigned int current,
                                unsigned int low, unsigned int high)
{
   sPRIME_THREAD *thread = (sPRIME_THREAD *)malloc(sizeof(sPRIME_THREAD));

    thread->num = num;
    thread->current = current;
    thread->low = low;
    thread->high = high;

    return thread;
}

void destroy_thread(sPRIME_THREAD *thread)
{
free(thread);
}

 void print_info(sPRIME_THREAD *thread)
 {
 printf("Num: %d\n", thread->num);
 printf("Current: %d\n", thread->current);
 printf("Low: %d\n", thread->low);
 printf("High: %d\n", thread->high);
 }
```

Comment: remove `extern` and make sure that it is not defined in anywhere

Comment: @LilithDeficiency by removing `struct` keyword in functions, the program compiled successfully

Comment: That is weird, it didn't work for me even when I double checked I didn't had any more extern declarations.